# Does anyone know of any VB.Net code generation plug-ins for StarUML?

Tags: vb.net, uml, code-generation, staruml

Simple question really.  No elaboration required.

I have found similar tools for Java, C#, C++ and other languages but not VB.Net.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know of a plugin for StarUML that will generate VB.NET code, however, if using a different modelling tool is a possibility, [Sparx System's](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html) will generate code in [VB.NET](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/uml_tool_guide/code_engineering/codeengineering.html) (as well as many other languages).

> Enterprise Architect enables you to
>   generate source code from UML model
>   elements, creating a source code
>   equivalent of the Class or Interface
>   element for future elaboration and
>   compilation. In particular you can
>   generate C, C++, C#, Delphi, Java,
>   PHP, Python, ActionScript, Visual
>   Basic and VB.NET source code. The
>   source code generated includes Class
>   definitions, variables and function
>   stubs for each attribute and method in
>   the UML Class.

Unfortunately, Enterprise Architect is not free nor is it open source, however, there is a full functional 30 day trial available, along with discount options for academic pricing (if appropriate).

If you're looking to stay with free and/or open source software, I think the closest for VB.NET code generation would be to use a couple of tools in conjunction with each other:

[Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia) is an open source, GTK+ based diagram creation program for Linux, Unix and Windows released under the GPL license.  You can use this to create your UML diagrams.  From there, you would use:

[Project: CodeGen](http://forge.novell.com/modules/xfmod/project/?codegen) from Novell, which will take the UML diagrams saved/exported from Dia and convert them into skeleton C# or VB.NET code.

If you're prepared to look at a more "general purpose" code generator, this page:
[Generators that build VB.NET](http://www.codegeneration.net/generators-by-language.php?language=31)
will give you a good starting list of tools that will generate VB.NET code.

Comment: This all looks like really useful stuff.  Thank you so much!  I had given this question up for dead.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @F5ToDebug - No problem.  Glad I could help, and it's because I went through the exact same thing only a few months ago.